# Yii same model saved twice, AJAX Validation

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii

I need to save model twice with different data:

**Controller:**

```
 $modelClient = new Client;

 if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
    echo CActiveForm::validateTabular( array( $modelClient));
    Yii::app()->end();
 }
```

**View (only relevant part of it)**

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($modelClient, '[0]name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($modelClient, '[0]street'); ?>

<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($modelClient, '[1]name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($modelClient, '[1]street'); ?>
```

**JSON OUTPUT**

```
{"Client_0_name":["field is empty"],"Client_0_street":["field is empty"]}
```

So the second model is just ignored.

**I tried**

```
if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
   foreach ($_POST[Client] as $client) {
    $temp = new Client;
    $temp->setAttributes($client);
    echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $modelClient));
   }
   Yii::app()->end();
}
```

but it returns JSON Output without the right id, eg.:

```
 {"Client_name":["field is empty"],"Client_street":["field is empty"]}
```

and as a result it just doesnt validate any of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you should declare the models as array.

```
 $modelClients=array();
 $modelClients[] = new Client;
 $modelClients[] = new Client;

 if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
    echo CActiveForm::validateTabular(  $modelClients);
    Yii::app()->end();
 }
```

And your first model goes to `$modelClients[0]` and second model to `$modelClients[1]`